# Partial output from file and progam not coming out of iterations

Tags: java

I am facing some problem while reading the contents of file.While the scenario is that
Example of file:

```
Australia____06092015_224554    
Baltic____06092015_131331   
Belux____06102015_000530    
Bulgaria____06092015_121454 
Chile____06092015_124625    
Colombia____06092015_123502 
Croatia____06092015_123520  
Germany____06102015_004530  
HongKong____06102015_030619 
Italy____06092015_134508    
Korea____06092015_212856    
Malaysia____06092015_230835 
Morocco____06092015_163055  
Netherlands____06092015_175635  
Poland____06092015_174550   
Romania____06092015_150912  
Russia____06102015_000734   
Serbia____06092015_153549   
Singapore____06102015_000841    
South Africa Sub Sahara 2____06092015_194840    
Spain____06092015_113544    
Thailand____06102015_110733     
Turkey____06102015_041318   
Ukraine____06102015_003746  
Uruguay____06092015_152429  
Vietnam____06102015_020824
```

But the output is:

```
Australia

Baltic

Belux

Bulgaria

Chile

Colombia

Croatia

Germany

HongKong

Italy

Korea

Malaysia

Morocco

Netherlands

Poland

Romania

Russia

Serbia

Singapore

SouthAfricaSubSahara

Spain

Thailand

Turkey
```

While the total input file row were 26 but only 23 are getting accessed in output till String "Turkey" and my program even not coming out in cmd. So i guess it is getting struck at String "Turkey" but don't know why actually?

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
public class tst {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        FileInputStream fin;
        int k = 0;
        String line, s, g, d;
        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            //DriverManager.registerDriver( new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.195.100:1521:ROW0", "azglobal_users_prd", "catcat1");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            fin = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/BOT2/Desktop/OGL/MC_WIth_DATA_Files.txt");

            DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fin);

            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));


            while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
                k++;
                s = line.replaceAll("[0-9_]+", "");

                g = s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

                System.out.println(g);

                d = "update ogl_table_status set status = 1 where mc_name='" + g + "'";
                stmt.executeUpdate(d);
            }

            System.out.println(k);
            stmt.close();
            br1.close();
            fin.close();

        }
        // Catches any error conditions
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to read from file");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements. Do you get any exception?

Comment: You can debug your code to see what's going wrong.

Comment: this works fine for me .[sout part]

Comment: it works fine for me... may be problem in sql code

Comment: Working fine here too. Remove the database update to see if it's better. You may have a hang up on DB connection. Also you don't need the `DataInputStream` put `fin` in `InputStreamReader` constructor directly

Comment: Are you sure there exists a `mc_name = Ukraine`,

Comment: @UmaKanth Yes there is mc_name = Ukraine

Comment: @ParaSara it is working fime for me till i am not upating DB by stmt.executeUpdate(d)...as i use this my DB conection geting struck at Turkey...

Answer (score 1):

If you could do,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:/MC_WIth_DATA_Files.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int idx = line.indexOf('_');
            String nation = idx > 0?line.substring(0, idx):line;
            System.out.println(nation);
        }
        br.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: This code doesn't solve the problem. This part is working fine. Problem is with DB update.

Comment: @ code-panda your code works fine ,resolves my prob..but throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException  at line  String nation = line.substring(0, idx)..

Comment: @Mohit Darmwal yes, if string not contains '_', this expection would be happened at runtime, so I had fixed it after edit answer.

Comment: @code-panda your code works fine..but again if i integrate this too my DB code again it getting hault and last 3 data rows in file are never accessed

Comment: @Mohit Darmwal could you paste last 3 data rows here? and others can let me help you.

Comment: @code-panda thanks ..issue has been resolved problem was due to DB session lock